# Some problems getting a button value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure I'm using this properly, but I need some help. I want to make a calculator, and I don't want to repeat code in html like `onclick="insert(value)"` so I wrote that code that would add an eventlistener on every button but I'm not sure how should I get the value of the button. At the moment text.value is [object MouseEvent]. I think I need something like btn.value but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
for(const btn of btns){
    btn.addEventListener("click", function insert(value) {
        text.value = text.value + value; 
    })
};
```

Comment: have you read the documentation for the [`Event` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) yet?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `btn.textContent`?  `button` elements do not have a `value` property. Or are you using `<input type="button" />` instead of a `<button>` element?

Answer (score 2):

First of all. When you take a value from a html component you are taking a string.
You should use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to convert these values in numbers.

the other thing is the html elements they are object in js with properties. You can use the function `console.log` and make you its best friend :) because although it is not a good practice all the time will help you a lot. When you log the element you can see how you can extract the value inside an Html Element. Normally all the HTMl Elements have a property called  `innerText` and `innerHtml` with them you can extract the value inside. For the inputs type elements you have the property `value` to extract the value inside the element.

I couldn't understand what exactly are you trying to achieve but i supose is something like make the sum of entered values. One last and not more important thing is that if you are expecting some value in js and is undefined or null or isNaN you will not get the result you are expecting for. For that reason you should always ask first if what you are expecting for is what you are receiving.

```html
<div class='container'>
  <input type='text' id='display' />
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
</div>
```

```js
const buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('button'));
const display = document.getElementById('display');

for (const btn of buttons) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const buttonValue = parseInt(event.target.innerText);
    const displayValue = display.value;
    if (displayValue.length === 0) {
      display.value = buttonValue;
      return;
    }
    display.value = parseInt(displayValue) + buttonValue;
    console.log(displayValue);
    console.log(buttonValue);
  })
};
```

[Here the codepen if you want to see it :)](https://codepen.io/Ruben1985/pen/qBOGNpb?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

Everything I had to do was to add .target.value.

```
text.value = text.value + value.target.value;
```